# Calculating sum of values

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently making a program that will have the user input a number which equals how many elements an array will have, when the user has input a number it saves to the array. Then I have a function that will get the sum of the elements in the array and save it to an int. My problem is that when it saves to the int and I press the same function again, it doubles the number.
For an example if the sum of the array is 5 and I press the function from my menu it will say 5, when I press sum again it will say 10. How do I make it not double?
My int sum is global since more functions need to access it.

```
int* talSerie = new int[num]; (global)
int num; (global)

void sumOfUserInput() {
    int summa = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++)
    {
        sum += talSerie[a];
        summa = sum;
    }
    Menu();
}
```

I know it has something to do with += but I don't know how to reformat it, is there a better way?

Comment: What is `sum`, and why is it needed (i.e. why not add directly to `summa`)?

Comment: Ops, sorry, im using int sum = 0; but I guess I could just use summa

Comment: Take a look at the loop condition again, that doesn't look quite right. Also, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and also please include all input and all expected and actual output. For example, without knowing what is `talSerie` and what values it contains it's hard to answer your question without guessing.

Comment: You need post a [mcve].

Comment: What more do I need to add

Comment: If this really is a C++ program (and not just C masquerading as C++) then you should be using [**std::accumulate**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: My teacher hasn't showed me that yet, the std::accumulate but I'll read it through

Comment: @NiklasErizkn: OK - if you're just getting started then stick with what your teacher has told you so far - be aware for future reference though that there are better ways...

Comment: Global variables are initialized to be zero, but global variables in a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (essentially a source file with all included header files) are initialized *in the order they are declared*. That means when you declare an initialize `talSerie` the variable `num` has not been initialized yet, and you will have *undefined behavior*. What's worse, even if you rearrange the order, then `num` will be zero, and you allocate a zero-sized array where *all* indexes will be out of bounds, which will also lead to UB.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int num = 1000; // change this value accordingly
int* talSerie = new int[num];

void sumOfUserInput() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < num; a++)
    {
        sum += talSerie[a];
    }
    Menu();
}
```

If you're still getting errors, make sure talSerie is fine, that is, I mean, make sure talSerie is filled up with the correct values debugging it.

Your `num` must be initialized before your `talSerie` as it's used for the array size.

Comment: The OP has commented that they do initialize `sum` with 0.  The real problem lies in the for condition.

Comment: Niklas, if it works, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
x=10;
int *myArray;                //Declare pointer to type of array
myArray = new int[x];   //use 'new' to create array of size x
myArray[3] = 10;          //Use as normal (static) array
...
delete [] myArrray;       //remeber to free memeory when finished.
```

you can use also use a vector like so

```
int x;
in >> x;
int* array = new int[ x ];
// use array here ...
delete [] array;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?

Comment: Earlier version of the question asked also how to create an array based on a variable size. the dialogs and edits here are changing so fast, by the time you answer something it's irrelevant